# Twitter data fetching using flume

Tags: hadoop, twitter, flume

Trying to fetch Twitter data but getting this error: java_home not set while other services running fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it seems your JAVA_HOME is not set.  you can tell flume which java to use.  in `flume/conf/flume-env.sh` set `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/share/java/jdk1.8.0_66/jre`.  the location flume-env.sh is dependent on how you installed it.